# How to fix unset json object in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, laravel-5

I have below json object,

```
{
"products": [{
        "type": "HR_ECLAIM",
        "name": "HR Claims",
        "is_fixed_price": true,
        "price": 500.5,
        "currency": "MYR",
        "status": "true"
    },
    {
        "type": "HR_ELEAVE",
        "name": "HR Leave",
        "is_fixed_price": true,
        "price": 500,
        "currency": "MYR",
        "status": "false"
    },
    {
        "type": "FIN_ADVISORY",
        "name": "Finance Advisory",
        "is_fixed_price": false,
        "currency": "MYR",
        "status": "true"
    }
],
"total_invoices": "100-600",
"total_staffs": "500-400",
"google_drive_url": "https:\/\/drive.google.com\/open?id=1Is6QsnuMLu9ZIpqeEzR2O2Ve1wUyF92aVCg55kWsOgc",
"remark": "",
"status": "pending"
}
```

I want to remove all the products that have **status = 'false'**

I some how fix above problem using below code. but,

```
$orders = (new Agos())->load($id);
        $json = $orders->data;
        $json = json_decode($json);

foreach($json->products as $k=>$v) {
        foreach ($json->products[$k] as $key=>$value) {
            if ($key === "status" && $value === "false") {

                unset($json->products[$k]);
            }
            json_encode($value, true);
        }

    }
```

and it return output like this,

```
{"products":{"0":{"type":"HR_ECLAIM","name":"HR Claims","is_fixed_price":true,"price":500.5,"currency":"MYR","status":"true"},"2":{"type":"FIN_ADVISORY","name":"Finance Advisory","is_fixed_price":false,"currency":"MYR","status":"true"}},"total_invoices":"100-600","total_staffs":"500-400","google_drive_url":"https:\/\/drive.google.com\/open?id=1Is6QsnuMLu9ZIpqeEzR2O2Ve1wUyF92aVCg55kWsOgc","remark":"","status":"pending"}
```

can someone helps to remove 0 and 2 from products output.

Can some one helps me to fix this?

Comment: Why do you say: remove products where `status` === `false` and then you close your question saying: _can someone helps to remove 0 and 2 from products output._ these have `status` === `true`, don't they?

Comment: yes i need to remove status  = false but after update code run it change original json output with 0 and 2 index in products that i need to remove from output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if `json_output['order_info']['products']` is correct as there is no `order_info` in the JSON data in your question, but just assuming that this part is correct.

The main issue is your `unset()` is just unsetting the value used in the `foreach` loop and not removing anything from the original array.  So if you use the original array and the index you have in the loop, you should be able to remove the items with `false`

```
unset($products[$hitsIndex]);
```

In your output, you have `true` as the second parameter to `json_encode` - this should be some form of option and not just `true` - something like `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`.

**Update:**

After the code edit in your question, the new version should be something like...

```
foreach($json->products as $index => $product) {
    if ( $product->status == "false") {
        unset($json->products[$index]);
    }
}
$json->products = array_values($json->products);
echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```